# How do I make a shortcut to close: call OpenTerminal () from vim?

Tags: vim

I'm new to vim and I'm practicing using the terminal, with the

```
: call OpenTerminal ()
```

however to exit I have to strictly type exit, so I would like to know how to return to normal mode in that terminal and do a

```
: q!
```

or at once close it using a map to save more time when carrying out my projects

Comment: Is `OpenTerminal` a function you've written? Typically, the commands to open are `:term` and `:vert term` for horizontal and vertical splitting, respectively.

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue? If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. However, there is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.vimrc` file.

`tnoremap <Esc> <C-\><C-n>:q!<CR>`

The `t` in `tnoremap` means it only applies to terminals. Then I just remapped the escape key to `<C-\><C-n>` go to normal mode, then execute `:q!` and press enter with `<CR>`. You can modify to whatever key mapping you want.